# Tumblr - Trigger an endpoint with 1x1 Image html tag

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-html

I need to trigger an endpoint with an 1x1 Image HTML tag in Tumblr post, like

```
<img src="https://sp.analytics.xyz.com/spp.pl?a=10000&.yp=123456">
```

However, when publishing the article, Tumblr revises my code automatically, and changes image `src` to `data-orig-src`.

```
<figure data-orig-height="1" data-orig-width="1" data-orig-src="https://sp.analytics.xyz.com/spp.pl?a=10000&.yp=123456">

<img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/cbf15a210669256dbc49a31f7eb220ee/f19e6bf3d440a355-d2/s540x810/5d384ea84df0a88b56add861897d009d2f77e147.gif" data-orig-height="1" data-orig-width="1" data-orig-src="https://sp.analytics.xyz.com/spp.pl?a=10000&.yp=123456" alt="image">
```

It causes the 1x1 image not being loaded on the page.

Is there a workaround to change it back?

Comment: Welcome to SO. A simple way of displaying code is to indent it with 4 spaces. There are some [other ways for formatting code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) as well.

Comment: Can you post a link to your tumblr, where are you trying to do this. You might need some js method.

Comment: Also are you making an image post (text posts will allow image upload, but I wonder if the post type is an image to begin with)